# Visualizing data in R [Beginner to R]

Tags: r, plot

I am a beginner in R and require help in visualizing some data. I am trying to plot the value of HDI of countries from 1990-2017.

My collated data is as such for example:

```
Country Year HDI
Brunei  1990 0.782
Brunei  1991 0.787
...
Brunei  2017 0.853
...
Cambodia 1990 0.364
...
Cambodia 2017 0.582
```

The data follows for countries as such.
My code is currently as such:

```r
x = ggplot(data=Collated.Data, aes(x=Year, y=HDI)) +
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  labs(x="Years 1990-2017", y="Value of HDI") +
  ggtitle("HDI of Country over the years") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=POT$Country), hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

The code shows this for instance, when I am covering ten countries:

[image]

How would I clean this graph and also add the country at the end? Would really appreciate some help on this matter :)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of the dataset in order we help you at the best.

For your plot, based on your code, I think you should try:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Collated.Data, aes(x=Year, y=HDI, group = as.factor(Country))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Years 1990-2017", y="Value of HDI") +
  ggtitle("HDI of Country over the years") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5)
```

It should plot the `HDI` in function of `Year` for each `Country`. All `Country` names and associated colors should appear in the legend and make your plot much more lisible.

I can't provide you an example of the final graphic because I don't have an example of your dataset to work with

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How would I provide a reproducible example of my dataset? I could send a link which includes the dataset.

Comment: As it is mention in the link, you should enter `dput(droplevels(Collated.data[1:50,]))`. It should provide the structure of the file for at least two country which is plenty enough to show you how to do it.